# How to create Python Regex that replaces characters?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I am having trouble in finding the way to create a proper regex that replaces in a string anything different from a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and |.

Until now, I have:

```
 re.sub(r'[\W_]+', '', s)
```

This works fine for alphanumerical characters, but I also need to make it work for pipe ("|"). Does anyone know how to make it?

For example, if I have:

```
name&|surna.me|ag,e
```

I need it like:

```
name|surname|age
```

Answer (score 5):

> anything different from a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and |.

You need a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
s = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9|]+', '', s)
```

A `[` starts the character class, `^` tells the regex engine that it should match anything other than what is defined inside the class, and the rest are your ranges/chars. `]` closes the class and `+` makes it match 1 or more occurrences of the required chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RrTHDg/1) and a [Python demo](http://ideone.com/U38UUs):

```
import re
s = 'name&|surna.me|ag,e'
s = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9|]+', '', s)
print(s)
# => name|surname|age
```